# Global variable not showing

Tags: powerapps

I'm trying to make an global variable that counts numbers up to 50 and stops all input if the variable reaches < 50
I've tried declaring a global variable in the OnStart function and tried displaying it in a Label but the numbers dont show, what am I doing wrong?

code in "OnStart": Set (Amount;0)
code in a Label: Amount

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Once you declare a variable in your onStart event, you have to let PowerApps know that your variable exists. you can do this by forcing onStart again. I have added a picture of this, simply click on the imgur link. Good luck!

[Run onStart to get your variable in memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vodc1.png)

Comment: Thanks a lot now the variable is showing. but now I got a new problem, I've made a button that "OnSelect" counts my variable + 1.  code: (Amount + 1) but again when I press the button the Variable stays on the default value 0 and isn't counting up.

Comment: Sounds easy.  Instead of the onSelect property amount + 1, you need to tell it what it should do, in this case save the value to your Amount variable. Your onSelect therefor should not be Amount + 1 but: Set( Amount, Amount + 1 )

Comment: Okay that also works now thanks XD, but my last 3 questions: I want the variable to be saved even if the app gets closed, it also should stop when it reaches 50 and then it should deactivate the button.

Comment: Late answer, but.....

Disable after it reaches 50:

On the button's displaymode you can set:

If( YourVariable < 50, Displaymode.Edit, Displaymode.View )

Or even hide the button complete on the visible property, where the FX in visible should be: YourVariable < 50

For the first part, save it to a dataverse table, a sharepoint list or something else